# While pushing vector<int> into vector <vector<int> >, SIGABRT - free(): invalid next size (fast)

Tags: c++, vector, sigabrt

> Hello to all, I am trying to write a function which will return a
>   vector of all permutations of a given vector. For eg, for input [1,2],
>   the output should be [[1,2], [2,1]]. For input [1,2,3], output should
>   be [[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1]]. Note that
>   the order of the permutations is not important in the output vector.

- I have used the the following logic to recursively generate the permutations :

  - the function takes a vector as input, returns vector< vector > as output.
  - if the size of the input vector is 1, i.e. input vector = [int], the output is [ [int] ]
  - else :

    1. remove ELEM = first element from the input vector V, and V' is the new vector with first element erased
    2. find permutations of V' with a recursive function call.
    3. for each permutation vector in permutations(V'), create a new permutation vector by inserting ELEM at all possible positions and append this newly created permutation vector to the final output to be returned.
- Given below is a test case :

  - input vector = [1,2]
  - expected output = [[1,2], [2,1]]
  - Test Case :

    1. 1 is taken as ELEM, [2] becomes V'
    2. permutations of V' i.2. [2] are [[2]] since it is the base case of recursion
    3. then, for every permutation in permutations(V') i.e. for [2] in [[2]], we add ELEM 1 at all positions which will be [1,2] and [2,1]. These newly created permutations are to be added to the final vector which returns the permutations.

### Following is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

ostream & operator <<(ostream & out, vector<int> printVector) {
    out << "[ ";
    for(int i=0; i<printVector.size();i++) {
        out << printVector[i] << " ";
    }
    out << "]";
    return out;
}
ostream & operator <<(ostream & out, vector< vector<int> > 
printVectorOfVectors) {
    out << "[" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<printVectorOfVectors.size(); i++) {
        out << printVectorOfVectors[i] << endl;
    }
    out << "]";
    return out;
}

vector< vector<int> > generatePermutations(vector<int> baseVector) {
    if(baseVector.size() == 1) {
        vector< vector<int> > temp;
        temp.push_back(baseVector);

        // DEBUG
        cout << "ROOT CASE , RET PERM : " << endl << temp << endl;
        // \DEBUG

        return temp;
    }
    else {
        vector< vector<int> > temp;
        int elem = baseVector[0];

        baseVector.erase(baseVector.begin());
        // DEBUG
        cout << "ELEM : " << endl << elem << endl;
        cout << "BASE VECTOR : " << endl << baseVector << endl;
        // \DEBUG

        vector< vector<int> > processPermutationsVector = generatePermutations(baseVector);

        // DEBUG
        cout << "PROCESS PERMS : " << endl << processPermutationsVector << endl;
        // \DEBUG

        for(int i=0; i<processPermutationsVector.size(); i++) {
            vector<int> v_i = processPermutationsVector[i];

            // DEBUG
            cout << "V_i : " << endl << v_i << endl;
            // \DEBUG

            for(int k=0; k<v_i.size()+1; k++) {
                vector<int>::iterator it = v_i.begin();
                cout << "k : " << k << endl;
                cout << "ORG PERM : " << endl << v_i << endl;
                v_i.insert(it+k, elem);
                cout << "PUSH PERM : " << endl << v_i << endl;
                temp.push_back(v_i);
                cout << "RET PERMS : " << endl << temp << endl;                    
                v_i.erase(it+k);
                cout << "CLEANED PERM : " << endl << v_i << endl;

            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> testVector{1,2};
    cout << "TEST VECTOR : " << endl << testVector << endl;

    vector< vector<int> > testPermutationsVector = generatePermutations(testVector);
    cout << "TEST PERMUTATIONS VECTOR" << endl << testPermutationsVector << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### The code gives the following output :

```
TEST VECTOR : 
[ 1 2 ]
ELEM : 
1
BASE VECTOR : 
[ 2 ]
ROOT CASE , RET PERM : 
[
[ 2 ]
]
PROCESS PERMS : 
[
[ 2 ]
]
V_i : 
[ 2 ]
k : 0
ORG PERM : 
[ 2 ]
PUSH PERM : 
[ 1 2 ]
RET PERMS : 
[
[ 1 2 ]
]
CLEANED PERM : 
[ 2 ]
k : 1
ORG PERM : 
[ 2 ]
PUSH PERM : 
[ 2 1 ]
RET PERMS : 
[
[ ]
[ 2 1 ]
]
CLEANED PERM : 
[ 2 ]
double free or corruption (out)
```

The code executed on codechef online c++ ide gives a runtime error of SIGABRT as - Error in `./prog': free(): invalid next size (fast). 
The newly created permutation is not being inserted in the vector of vectors "temp". Please help.

Comment: You will need to debug your code, we will not do this for you.

Comment: Since I was working on an online ide, I have used cout statements to debug. The "RET PERMS" statement prints out the contents of the final vector, that's empty even after pushing the permutations.

Comment: Your function `generatePermutations` does not correctly handle an empty vector.  It causes undefined behavior.  Your `printVectorOfVectors[0]` should be `printVectorOfVectors[i]`.

Comment: You can only get so far with online IDE (and this is not very far). I suggest you download and install a proper IDE.

Comment: @ccpak printing diagnostics is often a good start. Another helpful tool: https://www.onlinegdb.com/ This allows you to inspect the behaviour of a one translation unit program, stepping through it line by line if need be. A more complex program will require an offline development environment.

Comment: It might help understanding to replace `for(int i=0; i<printVectorOfVectors.size(); i++) {
        out << printVectorOfVectors[0] << endl;
    }` with `for(int i=0; i<printVectorOfVectors.size(); i++) {
        out << printVectorOfVectors[i] << endl;
    }`

Comment: I changed the index for `printVectorOfVectors[i]` as per comments from@Drew Dormann and @john. I also ran the code through gdb. @SergeyA, i checked the values in `temp` for each loop run, the vector `v_i` is appended in `temp` during an iteration of the loop, however for the next iteration, this vector appended in the last iteration is not accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
v_i.insert(it+k, elem);
```

invalidates the iterator `it` but that iterator is used again here

```
v_i.erase(it+k);
```

The alternative code

```
v_i.insert(v_i.begin()+k, elem);
```

and

```
v_i.erase(v_i.begin()+k);
```

runs without crashing. And with the fix to the `operator<<` already mentioned seems to give the correct result.

Comment: thanks, that did it! I did not understand how an offset invalidates the iterator though. Could you point me to a reference about iterators? It's time for me to hit the books again. Is the iterator  invalidated because I updated that vector? The iterator `it` was created for the data structure before it was updated, so once it has been updated, it requires its own iterator?

Comment: @ccpak It's not the offset that's the problem, the iterator is invalid before you add the offset. If you add an element to a vector then potentially any iterators to the vector become invalid. Essentially adding an element to a vector may cause the vector to reallocate it's internal storage, if that happens then any existing iterator will still be pointing at the old storage.

Comment: thanks again, that clears up the confusion about iterator invalidation. However, in gdb, by observing the `temp` variable, it's seen that `v_i` added during the last iteration of the loop becomes inaccessible in the current iteration. How does an iterator to `v_i` figure into that? Because erase method on `v_i` works using the same iterator. Shouldn't the erase method produce an erratic output, instead of the push_back method on `temp`?

Comment: @ccpak Once you have called the erase method with an invalid iterator you are into the realm of undefined behaviour. Anything is possible then. One of the things that makes debugging C++ hard, is that a crash or strange behaviour often occurs sometime after the execution of the code that was at fault.

Comment: thanks. This was tricky to understand just by observing the debugging output, as the problem was apparent only at `temp.push_vack(v_i)` statement. Your explanation has cleared it up.